# KMS-активация MS Office 2010 в PlayOnLinux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, office, активация

Какой адрес лицензионного сервера вводить при KMS-активации MS Office 2010 через эмулятор PlayOnLinux в Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1):

Для установке лицензионной программы воспользуйтесь подготовленным скриптом в PlayOnLinux, либо используйте портативную версию MS Office.

[Проблемы активации](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982748)